# Show/Hide multiple, layered jQuery UI widgets

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm new to all this so please bear with me.

I've been using some jQuery UI widgets and I'm wanting to create category (adults) radio buttons with their own set of subcategories (children) that only appear when the appropriate adult is selected.

Here's the code I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/99azd/

The problem is only the formatting of the initial set of children work, the others show up as plain checkboxes. I think it has something to do with the **div id="format"** but I'm not sure.

```
<div style="display: none;" id="Adult1Children">
  <div id="format">
    <input type="checkbox" id="child1" value="child1"/><label for="child1">child1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="child2" value="child2"/><label for="child2">child2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just found one error in the code, line 54, the id was set to the same as line 53. Unfortunately, that didn't change the output. Here's the revised code: http://jsfiddle.net/2bhZH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some help from the IRC channel - here's the fixed code:
http://jsfiddle.net/w6qFC/

I had a duplicated id "format" so it only ran the first one. All I had to do was change the id to a class instead and then in the js change from #format to .format. Simple.

```
$( ".format" ).buttonset();

and

<div class="format">
```